# Add points to user shows no errors but doesn't add

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a option in the Admin page where a admin can Select a user and add points to them, however I write the name and how many points to add, enter it and it shows up with no errors but saying it has been successfully added, but the points have not been added to that user...
Here's my code for the page with the form:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'add');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1;
        }
    }
 }

    if (empty($errors) === false) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' doesn\'t exist';
        }
    }
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
    echo 'The points have succesfully been added to the user!';
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $addpoints = array(
            'username'      => $_POST['username'],
            'add'       => $_POST['add']
        );
        addpoints($addpoints);
        header('Location: addthepoints352346.php?success');
        exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>

<h1>Admin Access Only</h1>
<p>Add points to a user</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    Username*:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </li>
                <li>
                    How many points to add*:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="add">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add">
                </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
<?php
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

And also another page with the function where it actually sends it to the     mysql database:

```
function addpoints($addpoints) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `points` = `points` + '$add' WHERE     `username` = '$username'");
}
```

I literally have no idea what it is, to help I have added a couple of photos
[image]
[image]

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9btck.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wd28I.png

Comment: One issue is that you are not passing variables named `$add` or `$username` to your `addpoints()` function, yet you are referencing them in your database query. You *are* passing an array called `$addpoints` so, given your current code, you should be referencing that array in your query. I suggest that you check for [PHP errors](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors) and [MySQL errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287132/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in-on-line

Comment: @showdev its not duplicate they are asking different things

Comment: Fair enough. Voting the close the other one as "can no longer reproduce".

Comment: right @showdev.......

Answer (score 0):

update your function as follows.

```
function addpoints($addpoints) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points = points +".$addpoints['add']."  WHERE    username = ".$addpoints['$username'].")";
}
```

Comment: can you echo query please.

Comment: @BrandonLukeTwyman Did you check for PHP and MySQL errors, as I suggested?

Comment: echo what query, I used the one that you have gave me

Comment: befor passing to mysql_query try to echo.....
echo "UPDATE users SET points = points +".$addpoints['add']."  WHERE    username = ".$addpoints['$username'].")"